# Angular-ui-router: ui-sref-active with child active

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular-ui-router and nested states in my application, and I also have a navigation bar. The nav bar is hand written, and uses ui-sref-active to highlight the current state. It is a two-level navigation bar.

Now, when I am in, say Candidate / Settings I would like both Candidate (in level 1) and Setting (in level 2) to be highlighted. However, using ui-sref-active, if I am in state Candidate.Settings then only that state is highlighted, not Candidate.

Candidate have sub-state - > bookmark, applicants
Setting have sub-state - > profile, password

I want to make active candidate and bookmark at a time while candidate should redirected to bookmark state on loading time.

I am able to make parent and child state active, but the problem is i want to load child state on clicking on candidate, and candidate and bookmark both should be active.

```
<ul class="ul-list">
      <li ui-sref-active="current"><a ui-sref="advertiser.candidate" data-ng-click="showPage('candidatePage')">Candidates</a></li>
      <li ui-sref-active="current"><a ui-sref="advertiser.settings" data-ng-click="showPage('settingsPage')">Settings</a></li>
      <li class="hide block bg-green"><a class="nav-link">Help</a></li>
      <li class="hide block bg-green"><a class="nav-link">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li><a ui-sref-active="current" ui-sref=".bookmarks" data-ng-click="loadCandiatePage('bookmarks')">Bookmarks <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref-active="current"  ui-sref=".applicants" data-ng-click="loadCandiatePage('applicants')"> Applicants</a></li>
  <li><a ui-sref-active="current"  ui-sref=".hired" data-ng-click="loadCandiatePage('hired')">Hired</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you please post your routing config so we can see your states setup?

Comment: .state('advertiser.candidate', {
   url: '/candidate',
   templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/advertiser/menuTabs/candidate/advertiser.candidate.html'
  })
  .state('advertiser.candidate.bookmarks', {
   url: '/bookmarks',
   templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/advertiser/menuTabs/candidate/advertiser.candidate.bookmarks.html'
  })
  .state('advertiser.candidate.applicants', {
   url: '/applicants',
   templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/advertiser/menuTabs/candidate/advertiser.candidate.applicants.html'
  })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.state('advertiser.candidate', {
            url: '/candidate',
            abstract: true,
            defaultChild: 'advertiser.candidate.bookmarks',
            templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/advertiser/menuTabs/candidate/advertiser.candidate.html'
        })
        .state('advertiser.candidate.bookmarks', {
            url: '/bookmarks',
            templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/advertiser/menuTabs/candidate/advertiser.candidate.bookmarks.html'
        })
```

and click on candidate page i set $state.go('advertiser.candidate.bookmarks'), then it worked for me.

Comment: With controller above, i have one solution in html to keep active of parrent element when you select it's child. Example: <li ng-class="{active: $state.current.name.indexOf('candidate') !== -1}"><a ui-sref="app.home">Browse Journal</a></li>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-class` to set the desired class name by evaluating the `$state`.

To use `$state` if your view you need to make it available on the scope in the controller:

```
controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
   $scope.$state = $state;
}]);
```

Or if you want it to be available app wide without setting it in each controller you can define it on `$rootScope` with `.run`:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
   $rootScope.$state = $state;
})
```

In your view you can still use `ui-sref-active` and also use `ng-class` to evaluate the current state. For example (substitute your application logic):

```
<li>
    <a ui-sref-active="current" 
      ng-class="{'current': $state.current.name == 'advertiser.candidate'}" 
      ui-sref=".bookmarks" 
      data-ng-click="loadCandiatePage('bookmarks')">
        Bookmarks <span class="sr-only"></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: Add a Controller for your nav bar orin your existing controller where nav bar is included add the following

```
app.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.isActive = function(destination) {
        return destination === $location.path();
    }
}]);
```

**Step2**: In your nav bar

```
<li ng-class="{active: isActive('/home')}">
    <a ui-sref="app.home">Browse Journal</a>
</li>
```

That's it.